# How to change the server date where database present?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, operating-system

Is there any way to do change the server date time where my database present using script ?

I know it can be done by doing RDP. But is it possible using script.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Changing-the-date-and-time-in-SQL-Server-using-T-SQL)

*I do not recommand this, the link has a bunch of warnings*.

```
USE master 
go 
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo 02/16/2000 | date' 
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo 09:00:00 | time'
```